# How to display the full description of the product category on category header instead of just a few characters?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use a product category description in every products category in woocommerce, but i don't know how to show the full description. After a few words it just stops and shows "..."
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaOx5.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 general ways I'm aware the text would show `...` at the end. Either via code or by CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis;` If it's using the CSS method, then you got to inspect the element (try right-click on element and choose Inspect, or something similar to that), see which html tag has the style set and then remove it or override it in the stylesheet.

(BTW: If you notice that the full description is there when inspecting the element, then text-overflow CSS is most likely involved.)

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

If it's not CSS but done by code, then it's necessary to get more details on the code used for this to know how to change it. It can be done either by JavaScript or PHP and might be dependent on the WordPress Theme in use.

A quick solution is to observer the source code for the page. See if the full text is in use anywhere else on the page, and then use JavaScript to rewrite the text in the Description area based on it. Read more http://api.jquery.com/html/

Otherwise, you will have to find out if there are any API Hooks that can intercept the Description area to change the text. (Maybe https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description or http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_archive_description/)

Again it might be dependent on the theme. If you are not getting through, add the Theme name to your question, to try get more help.

Here's an example of how to use `woocommerce_archive_description`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woo_category_description' );
function woo_category_description() {
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
        $cat_desc = term_description( $cat_id, 'product_cat' );
        $description = '<div class="description">'.$cat_desc.'</div>';
        echo $description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking the css and the source code was the first thing i did. I didn't find anything. So i thought it should be php (a kind of limit just like the posts excerpt)...I tested your code and it worked. So thanks a lot. I had already lost a lot of hours searching! I will just hide the theme's category description html and show yours!